# Connect pooling problem with Netbeans 8 and Java

Tags: mysql, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish, connection-pooling

I am trying to complete the web tutorial 'Creating a simple web application using a MySQL database'. The NetBeans project name is 'IFPWAFCAD' and I am using GlassFish 5 and Java EE 5.

The database and its tables are listed correctly under Project Services, and the database shows as connected.

I am unable to deploy the application after attempting to create a connection pool. The xml files are as follows:

web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>Database for IFPWAFCAD application
        </description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/IFPWAFCAD</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/IFPWAFCAD" object-type="user" pool-name="IfpwafcadPool">
    <description>Accesses IFPWAFCAD database</description>
  </jdbc-resource>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="table" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="IfpwafcadPool" non-transactional-connections="false" ping="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" pooling="true" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" statement-cache-size="0" statement-leak-reclaim="false" statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="true">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mynewdatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="User" value="root"/>
    <property name="Password" value="23447HP"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show (a) the version of MySQL you are using, (b) any deployment errors being generated?

Comment: mysql5.7.21 
the IFPQAFCAD (run-deploy) log says it was successfully deployed, but when I look at the Glassfish Server Resources under Connection Pools, the IfpwafcadPool is not shown in the Netbeans Services section

Comment: running the project generates and exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/IFPWAFCAD"

Comment: the Glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib folder contains mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar

Comment: Thanks for the update. You can [edit] your question and add this new info there, for better visibility. Also, what about the Glassfish admin console at `localhost:4848` (rather than the NetBeans view)? Is the new pool listed there? I would rely on that, over what NetBeans is telling me (but I have only ever used the Glassfish admin pages, not the Netbeans resources for Glassfish - so that may not help...).

Comment: Yes, the Glassfish admin console lists the IfpwafcadPool.
Is the mysql driver in the wrong folder?  Not sure where it is supposed to be.

Comment: My apologies - I completely missed your earlier comment about "no suitable driver found". I deleted my last (irrelevant) comment.

Comment: No apologies necessary, I appreciate your time.  I think there must be an incompatability between glassfish, netbeans and mysql.  I am going to reinstall the former and start over.